# Nested lists in R to JSON for Power BI

Tags: r, json, nested-lists

I have created a dataset in R consisting of 800 observations of 20 variables, some of which are vectors (of varying length)
eg
observation1: var1=1, var2="a", vec1=c("a", "b", "c"), vec2 = c(1,2,3)
observation2: var1=1, var2="a", vec1=c("a"), vec2 = c(1,2,3,4,5)

I tried to create a single data frame but it doesn't like the varying length of the vectors, so currently the data exists as multiple vectors of length 800 (one for var1, one for var2 etc) and multiple lists of length 800 (containing vec1, vec2 etc)

Is the only way of combining this into a single data object to use a nested list?

Ultimately I need to output as a JSON to bring into Power BI, but I don't know how to combine the existing elements to achieve that. I tried creating a nested list and then toJSON(), but this does not resolve to a table with columns (in Power BI), rather each list item appears as a row which needs to be expanded into 800 rows.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you currently have:

```
vector_var1 <- c(1, 1)
vector_var2 <- c("a", "a")
list_vec1 <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a"))
list_vec2 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

You can put that in a dataframe with *list columns*:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  var1 = vector_var1,
  var2 = vector_var2,
  vec1 = I(list_vec1),
  vec2 = I(list_vec2)
)
```

This gives this JSON:

```
jsonlite::toJSON(dat, pretty = TRUE)
# [
#   {
#     "var1": 1,
#     "var2": "a",
#     "vec1": ["a", "b", "c"],
#     "vec2": [1, 2, 3]
#   },
#   {
#     "var1": 1,
#     "var2": "a",
#     "vec1": ["a"],
#     "vec2": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#   }
# ]
```

Is it what you need?

## EDIT

Following the discussion in the comments, here is how you can achieve the desired result, using `purrr::transpose` and `rlist::list.zip`:

```
vector_var1 <- c(1, 1)
vector_var2 <- c("a", "a")
list_vec1 <- list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
list_vec2 <- list(c(1,2,3), c(1,2,3,4,5))

L1 <- purrr::transpose(list(list_vec1, list_vec2))
L2 <- lapply(L1, function(vecs){
  do.call(rlist::list.zip, c(vecs, list(use.names=FALSE)))
})

dat <- data.frame(var1 = vector_var1, var2 = vector_var1, vec = I(L2))

jsonlite::toJSON(dat, auto_unbox = TRUE)
# [{"var1":1,"var2":1,"vec":[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3]]},{"var1":1,"var2":1,"vec":[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3],["d",4],["e",5]]}]
```

Comment: Great -thanks so much for answering - will try later on and let you know!
Much appreciated.

Comment: Great, thanks so much Stephane - that works exactly as requested!
Only thing is, what I actually need to do is tie the elements of each vector in the lists together so eg in observation 1, vec1[1] ("a") and vec2[1] (1) are related, as are vec1[2] ("b") and vec2[2] (2).. so I am now wondering if there's a better way I can structure the data so that it unfolds in Power BI correctly.

Comment: I realised that my example 2nd observation is incorrect since the length of each vector within a single observation must be equal so obsv 2, vec1 should be c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"). Apologies!

Comment: @esteebie I don't know Power BI and I don't see what you mean. Does something like `"vec": [["a",1], ["b",2], ["c",3]]` would be appropriate? Otherwise, could you show the output you expect?

Comment: Thanks Stephane, that is exactly what I needed and managed to achieve it by transposing with an inner and outer loop across existing data structures. If anyone reads this in future the only thing that tripped me up was not stating the field names explicitly in the new list objects.. Power BI needs that to recognise them as records and populate correctly as columns.

Comment: @esteebie Nice. Please see my edit. It shows how to get this result without loops.

Answer (score 0):

Since your ultimate goal is to import this dataset into powerBI, going by dataframe would be best, because in powerBI you would have to again convert it into tabular structure, so converting from dataframe to json and then json to dataframe is a bit of overdo.

Now coming to converting vectors of different length to a dataframe, you will get an error as the elements in dataframe need to have same length. So the trick is to make those elements of same length, by filling extra elements with NA (or any placeholder like 'blank').

```r
#function to generate vectors of varying length
temp_vectors = function(n){
  vector_list = vector('list', n)
  max_size = 0
  
  for(i in 1:n){
    vec_size = sample(1:20, 1)
    vector_list[[i]] = sample(1:10, vec_size, replace=TRUE)
    if(max_size < vec_size) max_size = vec_size
  }
  
  return(list('max_size' = max_size, 'vector_list' = vector_list))
}

x = temp_vectors(10)
vectors = x[['vector_list']]
n = x[['max_size']]

#the above code produces the following vector
vectors[1:2]
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 6 8 5 5 9 2 1 2 4 7 3 8
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 4 8 8 7 9

#for loop to fill the extra places with NA
for(i in 1:10){
  if(length(vectors[[i]] != n)){
    length(vectors[[i]]) = n
  }
}

vectors[1:2]
#> [[1]]
#>  [1]  6  8  5  5  9  2  1  2  4  7  3  8 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>  [1]  1  4  8  8  7  9 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

#combining the vectors into df
df = data.frame(vectors)
colnames(df) = paste0('col.', 1:ncol(df))
df
#>    col.1 col.2 col.3 col.4 col.5 col.6 col.7 col.8 col.9 col.10
#> 1      6     1     3     7     8     6     5     3     6      9
#> 2      8     4    NA     7    10     8     5     1     8     NA
#> 3      5     8    NA    10     5     9     7    NA     1     NA
#> 4      5     8    NA     4     4     2     8    NA     8     NA
#> 5      9     7    NA    NA     6     6     6    NA     9     NA
#> 6      2     9    NA    NA     5     4     7    NA     4     NA
#> 7      1    NA    NA    NA     1     1     2    NA     8     NA
#> 8      2    NA    NA    NA     9     7     6    NA     5     NA
#> 9      4    NA    NA    NA     4     8    10    NA     8     NA
#> 10     7    NA    NA    NA     3     6    NA    NA     1     NA
#> 11     3    NA    NA    NA     1     6    NA    NA     9     NA
#> 12     8    NA    NA    NA     6     7    NA    NA     8     NA
#> 13    NA    NA    NA    NA     6     8    NA    NA    10     NA
#> 14    NA    NA    NA    NA     2     8    NA    NA    10     NA
#> 15    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     9    NA    NA     5     NA
#> 16    NA    NA    NA    NA     2     3    NA    NA     2     NA
#> 17    NA    NA    NA    NA     1     1    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 18    NA    NA    NA    NA     6     6    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 19    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     9    NA    NA    NA     NA
#> 20    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA     9    NA    NA    NA     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note you can do the same with your 800 vectors, iterate through them and change their size to the size of longest vector, the extra indexes would be automatically filled with NA.

Comment: This is great - thanks so much! I can't see the option to connect to a data frame in Power BI tho, does it have to be via the R script?

I would be still be very interested to know how it would be done with a JSON if anyone can provide that solution.

Comment: you can export the dataframe into a csv file with `write.csv(df, 'filename.csv')` and then import into powerBI.